# How do I find out what the file-type of an image is?

Tags: images, conversion, jpeg, file-types

I have image that is not opening. However online convertors are able to convert it.

How do I retrieve the image format?

When opening file in text editor, the following information may be found:

`Creator: JasPer Version 1.600`

Comment: The `file` utility might be helpful in this case.

Comment: Or the `identify` utility from ImageMagick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JasPer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JasPer) is a library codec for JPEG-2000.

> As of 2012, [JPEG-2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG-2000) is not
>   widely supported in web browsers, and hence is not generally used on
>   the Internet.

Most JPEG images probably still use the 1992 [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg) Codec and the [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) and [JFIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFIF) file formats. So those are probably what a lot of software still assumes.